# relationship zookeeper and kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am learning kafka CLI. And have a question. 
why we have to use --zookeeper option when creating topics and consuming message, however when producing messages, we just use --broker-list ,which just refers to Kafka itself, 
1.create topics

```
 ./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper `docker-machine ip bigdata` --replication-factor 1  --partitions 1 --topic bigdata
```

2.produce message

```
 ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list `docker-machine ip bigdata`:9092 --topic bigdata
```

3.consume message

```
 ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper `docker-machine ip bigdata`:2181 --topic bigdata
```

I know kafka must use zookeeper for coordination. But I still don't get it very clear from the CLI commmand

Comment: This answer seems relevant to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444351/why-does-kafka-producer-take-a-broker-endpiont-when-being-initialized-instead-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to distinguish between topic management and topic consumption. ZK in not only used for broker coordination but also for topic management.

For topic management, ZK is used to store topic metadata and brokers do (currently, Kafka `0.10.1`) not offer an API for topic management. Thus, the admin CLI tools do actually talk directly to ZK (and not to the broker). This will change in the future, when the new "admin client" is fully implemented (c.f. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-4+-+Command+line+and+centralized+administrative+operations)

For topic consumption, ZK is not required and consumer and producer clients only talk to the brokers.

Comment: Thanks, so basically topic data itself still stores in kakfa nodes , right ?

Comment: Yes. ZK only stores metadata. You topic payload is stored in the Kafka brokers.